# Sort object keys by custom logic

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object in javascript that looks like this:

```
const inventory = {
   fall: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 2': [] },
   spring: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 3': [] },
   winter: { 'Category 3': [], 'Category 4': [] },
   summer: { 'Category 4': [], 'Category 5': [] }
}
```

How can I sort by keys so that those are ordered as follows:

1. spring
2. summer
3. fall
4. winter

Comment: Why do you need to sort them? You have 4 well defined properties that you can access by key. Are you iterating over them for some reason?

Comment: in JS you cannot sort by key like you can in PHP. You can have a look at some other similar questions with answers on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Comment: Yes, I'm iterating over them and sometimes they produce different output like spring, summer, winter, fall OR winter, fall, summer, spring. I want it to be consistent

Comment: Although object keys are iterated in a certain order, the rules for that can be a pitfall. Most agree that it is bad practice to rely on any order of object keys. If you need order, you should be using an array. Like: `[{season: "spring", category1: [], category2: []}, {season: "summer", .........]`

Comment: You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/38218582#38218582) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). but it's best not to rely on the default object ordering in js. If you want ordered pairs, use Maps

Comment: You could use Sets, they preserve the order: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

**Destructuring assignment**

```
const { spring, summer, fall, winter } = {
  fall: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 2': [] },
  spring: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 3': [] },
  winter: { 'Category 3': [], 'Category 4': [] },
  summer: { 'Category 4': [], 'Category 5': [] }
};

const inventory = { spring, summer, fall, winter }
```

Comment: This will create an object with the properties in the desired order, but JavaScript code that expects a particular ordering is a bad practice.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure about the question purpose

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create new object with this sorting.

```js
const inventory = {
   fall: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 2': [] },
   spring: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 3': [] },
   winter: { 'Category 3': [], 'Category 4': [] },
   summer: { 'Category 4': [], 'Category 5': [] }
}

const { fall, spring, winter, summer } = inventory;

const sortingInventory = {
  spring,
  summer,
  fall,
  winter,
}


console.log(sortingInventory)
```

**FOR SORTING ALGHPITICALLY**.

```js
const inventory = {
   fall: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 2': [] },
   spring: { 'Category 1': [], 'Category 3': [] },
   winter: { 'Category 3': [], 'Category 4': [] },
   summer: { 'Category 4': [], 'Category 5': [] }
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(inventory).sort((a, b) => {
  return a[0].localeCompare(b[0])
}))

console.log(result)
```